# T-bevel vs Protractor angle finder

Tags: wood, woodworking, carpentry

Is there something that a T-Bevel can do that a Protractor/Angle driver can't? The protactor is able to give the angle measure which is a plus.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep. It can fit in your pocket.

The whole point of a bevel gauge is to transfer angles as simply and compactly as possible. It's a carpenter's tool. You wouldn't want your utility knife to dice vegetables for you, and you don't want a fussy, clumsy tool in your belt pouch that you don't need.

Comment: Seems fair, I just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing some extra feature :) I find the bevel gauge much easier to use, and when I need to read the angle, I'll just measure it with the protractor!